# Django Python: Image Upload is not working not working

Tags: python, django, image, upload, social-media

I am working on a Social Media Website, the base code is from an Open Source Project on GitHub.
On the base project you can only post text.

I was looking around the Internet and found a instruction to implement img upload.

But it doesn't work, because i get a lot of error codes.

Error Code:

> AttributeError: module 'django.forms' has no attribute 'Post'

my Code:
forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import fields
from .models import Post, Comment

class Post(forms.Post): 
  
    class Meta: 
        model = Post
        fields = ['name', 'Main_Img']
```

posts.py

```
""" Home page with all posts """
def first(request):
    context = {
        'posts':Post.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/first.html', context)

""" Posts of following user profiles """
@login_required
def posts_of_following_profiles(request):

    profile = Profile.objects.get(user = request.user)
    users = [user for user in profile.following.all()]
    posts = []
    qs = None
    for u in users:
        p = Profile.objects.get(user=u)
        p_posts = p.user.post_set.all()
        posts.append(p_posts)
    my_posts = profile.profile_posts()
    posts.append(my_posts)
    if len(posts)>0:
        qs = sorted(chain(*posts), reverse=True, key=lambda obj:obj.date_posted)

    paginator = Paginator(qs, 50)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        posts_list = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        posts_list = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        posts_list = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
  
    return render(request,'blog/feeds.html',{'profile':profile,'posts':posts_list})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [...]
if settings.DEBUG:
 urlpatterns += static (settings.MEDIA_URL,
                              document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

models.py

```
""" Post model """
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    content = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    Main_Img = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/images/') 
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="blogpost", blank=True)
    saves = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="blogsave", blank=True)

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()

    def total_saves(self):
        return self.saves.count()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={"pk":self.pk})
```

post_form.py

```
<div class="m-auto w-100 container">
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
            {% csrf_token %} 
            {{ form.as_p }} 
            <button type="submit">Upload</button> 
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
```

This is the Website i got the code for the Img Upload from:
bit.ly/3IAKNQK

I have issues to implement them booth.

My problem is to sync the code from the website to my already existing code.

Comment: Where are you *using* that form? You did not share the view that uses the form...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is no class named `Post` in `django.forms` module.

I am not sure what example you are refering to as https://de.acervolima.com/python-bilder-in-django-hochladen returns 404 not found, but I guess you replaced some class name in the example.

In Django, file upload can be implemented using `FileField` in `django.forms`

These Docs might help.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/file-uploads/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files